# Use of the word 'naturally'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Dear fellow overflowers,

I was wondering I could use the word naturally in the sense of 'it goes without saying' or 'as would have been expected'.

An example sentence would be:

"The pasta I made today was so good, naturally."

Comment: It's (probably) technically correct, but it's not very idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an accepted use of *naturally*.

> **naturally** *adverb*
>
> 2 : according to the usual course of things : as might be expected
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naturally

Answer (score 2):

Goes without saying means that something is obvious, logical. Naturally stands for “as expected” (not unexpected). If we don’t already know that you are a good cook, naturally is not the best word in my opinion.